# how to check if a tab opened using window.open() is still running or shut or refreshed?

Tags: javascript, next.js, window.open

```
 const newWindow = window.open(
      "",
      "_blank",
      "width=800,height=600,left=2000,top=0"
    );

    if (newWindow) {
      const specificDivContent = document.getElementById(
        `slide-${slideIndex}`
      ).innerHTML;
```

above is the code i am using to create a new tab and write an existing div onto that tab. i would like to call an api when the new window that is opened is refreshed or closed.
tried using these listeners below.

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    // Prevent the user from leaving the page.
    console.log('tried closing the window')
    event.preventDefault();
  });
  
  function checkWindowClosed() {
    if (window.closed) {
      console.log('window closed')
    } else console.log('still open')
  }
  
  setInterval(checkWindowClosed, 1000);
```

Comment: You can't reliably detect a child window being closed from the parent. A better approach would be to detct the content of the child window being unloaded and use a [Beacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) to send your API request. Better still, don't use the popup at all, as it's likely to be blocked in modern browsers as popups are just plain annoying, and use a modal dialog in the current page instead.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking it on `newWindow` and not `window`?

Comment: I think the `pagehide` event could be useful here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, not using window.open() to create a popper, wanted a feature that would create a new window open and user would be able to use that as an extended display. for which i am using window.open(). i dont think modal would be useful for that usecase

Answer (score -1):

With a little error checking we'll know if accessing the window is successful...

```
try{

 newWindow.document.body.appendChild('<div>hello</div>'); // or some other operation

} catch(e){

 alert(e);

}
```